# Query inside a Transaction

Tags: hibernate, postgresql-8.4

I have a doubt about transactions and queries inside transactions.
Currently I'm using PostgreSQL 8.4 with Hibernate.

I don't know if it's possible to get the data that has been recently inserted in a transaction
if I execute a query inside the same transaction.

For example.

```
Begin Transaction();
       Save(A);
       Get(A);
End Transaction();
```

Will the query return the recently saved row?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it will. Transaction context makes the data invisible to other database transactions until this transaction is comitted.

If you are using Hibernate, the save() call would not necesserely write the object to the database because of the session cache (caches) immediately. But the consecutive get() would flush the session cache to the database and then would return the recently created object.

Comment: Well this is odd then, because I'm Currently doing a Save and then a Get, but The object isn't returned unless I do a flush and then a get. Maybe it's a problem with hibernate configuration, or maybe  I need to do something else.

Comment: What are you passing to the get()? How is your primary key set up? If it's an auto-increment or is set from a sequence, it might not be set on your object until the cache is flashed to the database.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you will get the data from session cache irrespective of saved it in db or not.